# Performant way to lex INDENT and DEDENT to pass to Earley?

Tags: parsing, haskell, earley-parser

Continuing from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ollef/Earley/issues/49):

I need to match on indent or dedent, and I'm using [Earley](https://github.com/ollef/Earley). Earley has no built-in support for indentation, but I'd like to be able to use indentation instead of braces in my language.

Example input:

```
func foo(a: A, b: B): C =
  theresSomeIndentRequiredHere(a, b)

func noMoreIndentMeansNoMoreFoo: D = ???
```

This would parse `theresSomeIndentRequiredHere` as part of `foo`, but `noMoreindentMeansNoMoreFoo` would not get parsed as part of `foo`.

How can I do this without losing a ton of speed?

Comment: If it's speed you're after, you should not be using an Earley parser.  Are you doing something fancy with an ambiguous grammar that you need an Earley parser for?

Comment: Also consider starting off by writing a correct algorithm, without worrying about its performance. Then measure it: if it's unacceptably slow, implement it again: it will be easier for having done it once the easy way already.

Comment: @luqui I am not, actually. What should I be using then?

Comment: I rechecked a comparison of parsing libraries, specifically the one in Megaparsec's readme. I think initially I read "Megaparsec is faster" as the opposite. That readme recommends attoparsec for speed, but I probably should just use Megaparsec. Even still, is there a good solution to this problem, with respect to Earley?